# Impedance matching and solar cells

Tags: electrical-resistance

Can you use impedance matching to calculate the internal resistance of a solar cell by finding out at what resistance on a variable resistor the power output is maximum and then making that equal the the internal resistance.

Answer (score 0):

That's one way, assuming all else is constant.  Another way is to measure the open circuit voltage and the short circuit current, keeping all else constant.  The internal resistance is then

$$R_S = \frac{V_{OC}}{I_{SC}} $$